# Jquery: i have a function $.fn.my_function with other functions inside, how can i call them?

Tags: jquery, function, extend

Suppose i have this ($ = jquery):

```
 $.fn.my_function = function() {
    function foo() 
    { 
       //do something 
    };

    function bar() 
    { 
       //do something other
    };

 }
```

I lauch this with `$('.my_class').my_function();`

Now, i need to call foo and bar on callback to certain events.

How can i call them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to expose them to the "outside world" somehow.   Currently, they are only visible within `my_function` so you won't be able to call them from anywhere else.

The most naive way to fix this would be something like:

```
var foo;
var bar;
$.fn.my_function = function() {
    foo = function() {
       //stuff
    };
    bar = function() {
       //stuff
    };
};
```

The same concept could be applied to place references to them anywhere that makes sense for your usage.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you're trying to build a jQuery plugin. You should constrain your plugin's methods to a private scope, and you should also iterate over the elements given to the plugin by the jQuery selector, and return them by using jQuery's "each" to preserve the chaining abilities:

```
// wrap the plugin code inside an anonymous function 
// to keep the global namespace clean   
(function($){
    $.fn.my_function = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            function foo() {
                // stuff here
            }
            function bar() {
                // stuff here
            }
            // now you can use your foo and bar which ever way you want
            // inside the plugin
            $(this).focus(function(event){
                // do some stuff
                ...
                // call the function defined previously in the plugin code
                foo(); 
            });
            $(this).blur(function(event){
                // do some stuff
                ...
                // call the function defined previously in the plugin code
                bar();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You might wanna have a look at  these articles for more info on jQuery plugin development:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

However, if you're doing just some "utility"-type functions, you can just tie them to jQuery namespace like this:

```
$.foo = function(){
         // do stuff
    };
$.bar = function(){
        // do stuff
    };
```

Comment: yes you've got the issue, almost.. i have to modify a plugin, extending its method for the world

+1 for the very good explanation :)

Comment: @antti That's some **goooood** boilerplate.  And that link - from the query site - is great.. I've seen it before.. and strangely - it is one of the most concise, well-worded, and rich pieces of programming "insight" i've ever read… as opposed to the rest of the jQuery site which "seems" like it was envisioned and executed by retarted schoolchildren in some third-world hell hole.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<p id="hello">aaa</p>
<p id="hola">sss</p>
<div id='result'></div>
```

JS

```
$.fn.my_function = function() 
{
    this.foo = function(xref) {
       $("#result").append("<div>"+xref+".foo " + $(this).html() +"</div>");
    };

    this.bar = function(xref) {
       $("#result").append("<div>"+xref+".bar " + $(this).html() +"</div>");
    };

    return this;
};

var ee1 = $("#hello").my_function();
var ee2 = $("#hola").my_function();

ee1.bar("ee1");
ee2.bar("ee2");
$("#hello").html("hello hellboy");
ee1.foo("ee1");
ee2.foo("ee2");
$("#result").append("<hr />");
ee1.bar("ee1");
ee2.bar("ee2");
$("#hola").html("hola hellboy");
ee1.foo("ee1");
ee2.foo("ee2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this situation, which is useful if you want to call your plugin's methods from elsewhere (perhaps a different file etc.) is to write the plugin logic as a class and then instantiate that class inside the jQuery plugin, storing the instance in `$.data`.

```
(function($) {

  var Animal = function(el, settings) {
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.settings = settings;

    this.foo();
  };

  Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
    // Do stuff
    if (this.settings.isVegetarian) {
      console.log('I eat plants');
    } else {
      console.log('I eat meat');
    }
  };

  Animal.prototype.play = function() {
    // Do other stuff but return this.$el so you can maintain chain
    return this.$el;
  };

  // Create jQuery plugin
  var pluginName = 'myPlugin';

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    // Defaults
    var settings = $.extend({
      isVegetarian: true,
    }, options );

    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, pluginName)) {
        // Store plugin instace with element (this), 
        // so public methods can be called later: 
        // $('.el').data('myPlugin').eat();
        $.data(this, pluginName, new Animal(this, settings));
      }
    });
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Then when you want to call your plugin, it's just like normal:

```
$('.dog).myPlugin();
```

and call a method:

```
$('.dog').data('myPlugin').eat();
```